# Pretty print XML data in JSP

Tags: html, xml, jsp, formatting, pretty-print

How do I pretty print (ie. with indentation) XML data in the JSP? I have the following code:

```
<c:forEach items="${stuffs}" var="stuff">
    <pre>
        <c:out value="${stuff}" escapeXml="true"/><br/>
    </pre>
</c:forEach>
```

But the problem is when `${stuff}` is an unformatted XML, it will show in the jsp as one long XML data. I need it pretty-printed inside the `<p>` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XSLT has a simple means of doing this via the `xsl:output` element. If you can apply an XSLT, I suggest using a stylesheet like this (based on the identity transformation):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You may or may not wish to use `xsl:strip-space`, but if you do, remember to use `xsl:preserve-space` should you need to e.g. retain whitespace-only text nodes within mixed content.

Comment: This seems to work for me out of several alternatives--but my <script> tags get stripped out of the result. Thoughts?

Comment: @aceofspades: Strange… Do you have a simple sample? I have had no issues with `script` tags when using the above transformation. Could it be a namespace issue? Can you reproduce it with simplified input documents? Which XSLT processors have you tried? Are you sure it is not an XML viewer problem?

Comment: I have more than a single top-level element. I'm assuming that is why. Thanks--

Answer (score 1):

If you want a simple solution, don't bother with xsl while setting response for JSP to look at, just do `stuff.replaceAll("<", "& lt;").replaceAll(">","& gt; ");` You don't need anything else; no XSL transformation needed here. Use technologies when they are essential, unless I am missing something here.

Answer (score 0):

You can pretty print JSLT with Pretty Diff at http://prettydiff.com/?m=beautify  It will do exactly what you need.  Consider the following example:

```
<a>
    <c:out value="<strong>some content</strong>"/>
</a>
```

Pretty Diff is capable of recognizing multidimensional tags so long as the nested tag is in quotes.