# Displaying content in a text area as XML

Tags: xml, jsp, textarea

I want to display content in Text Area as XML , Where content(uneditable) is available as Java String in the JSP.

Update : My xml response in textarea looks like,

[image: XML Response]

Comment: `<textarea>${theXML}</textarea>`?

Comment: I tried this, I am seeing the value as a plain string rather in XML form.

Comment: What do you mean by "XML form" then? Syntax highlighted, colored, collapsible?

Comment: Tree Structure will work for me, highlighted, colored, collapsible would be great additions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pretty print XML data in JSP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5903716/pretty-print-xml-data-in-jsp)

Comment: @RajeshLalam can you post the output obtained (image output), by edit your question.?

Comment: I added the sample screen , where i could see content as plain text in Text Area

Comment: My requirement  is different from the "Pretty print XML data in JSP" thread.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `textarea` use `preview` tag (it will preserve the line breaks) and `<c:out>` tag to display the xml string.

```
<pre>
    <c:out value="${xmlString}" />
</pre>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I need text area to display the content  for representation as the web page has many html attributes

Comment: Can you update your question with how you're getting?

Comment: Added the sample screen, Please let men know if more details are needed